# Something like "Extract String Resource" of Android Studio in FXML file JavaFX using IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, fxml

I interesting feature add string to strings.xml directly from XML file in Android Studio named "Extract String Resource".
So I wonder if there is feature to extract string to properties file from FXML file JavaFX using IntelliJ IDE?

Answer (score 0):

I found this. Seems like this is backward backward with Android Studio, we will defined the property entry name first(Ex: %txt_name), then using Alt+ Enter and select Create Property.
Hope this is helpful for JavaFx Newbie Developer like me :D